# Can I use a smart socket with an input voltage of AC 120V and plug it into a 220V outlet?

Tags: power, smart, sockets, voltage, international

Using a Smart Socket
Model SP10
Made by Teckin

It's meant for use in the USA with 120V power outlets but  it is being used in the Phillipines with 220V power outlets.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell from the brief description you provided.

Unless the device is **clearly** marked 90-125 Volts AND 210-245 Volts or 90-245 Volts, it may be dangerous to use.

If the voltage markings are limited to US / North American voltage of 90-125 Volts, then do NOT use it in a 220 Volt environment.